# 2 simple Regular Expressions

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am a newbie with regular expressions. I am trying to make 2 of them for my website:

The 1st one: Any characters can be used, but if there is a `<` and/or a `>` any where in the string, this is not allowed.

The 2nd one: The same as the above, except a zero-length or blank string is also not allowed.

All I have so far is maybe `[^<>]` for the 1st one, and maybe `^\S+$` in the 2nd one, but I don't think they even meet my requirements properly. Help appreciated.

(**Note**: I will be using these in an *ASP.NET* `RegularExpressionValidator` control)

Comment: Http://regexpal.com is a very handy website for this.

Comment: For the first one, you were close `^[^<>]*$` for the second you change `*` to `+`.

Comment: John - thanks for that link.

Comment: HamZa - Thanks. I am using John's link to test those. The first one appears to work properly. The 2nd one seems to fall over if I just enter some spaces. Maybe I am doing something wrong... Cheers.

Comment: @user3173098 So, by blank you mean "space-only or empty"?

Comment: Yes, I mean both "space-only" or "empty". If either is true, then validation should fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any characters can be used, but if there is a `<` and/or a `>` any where in the string, this is not allowed.

```
^[^<>]*$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO0bI4/1). `[^...]` is a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any character but the ones defined in it. `*` matches 0+ characters (thus, an empty match is allowed). `^` asserts the position at the beginning of the string and `$` - at the end.

> The same as the above, except a zero-length or blank string is also not allowed.

```
^(?!\s+$)[^<>]+$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO0bI4/2)

The `(?!\s+$)` [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) (`\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces and `$` asserts the position at the end of the string) here prevents matching a string that is whitespace only. The `+` quantifier matches 1+ characters (so, empty matches are not allowed).

Comment: Why not just change the second one to `^[^<>\s]+$`?

Comment: Not sure, would that do the same thing?

Comment: `^[^<>\s]+$` will not match strings like `A text`

Comment: James Buck: your version appears to not allow spaces between words, while the accepted answer does what I need.

Comment: Done :) I appreciate the speed and correctness of your answer.